# How to enable editing content of table view cell when edit action is performed

Tags: iphone, uitableview, edit

Hi everyone and I wish a very happy new year!

I have 2 view controllers,One where the user fills all the fields in the table view and clicks save,the data gets inserted in to table of sqlite database,I have already succeded inserting,updating,retrieving data from sqlite database table.

The other view controller where the user can view the saved data(My case:reminder).I have displayed the data saved successfully,i.e. when I save a reminder a cell gets added in view reminder page and the reminder saved in the instance gets displayed,similarly for each and every saved reminder and so on...

The user would well be interested and in need for editing the content he/she saves.So I have placed a edit button and I have implemented the orientation and deletion of the cell,but how can I edit the cell,i.e. how can I make the cell navigate to the add reminder page where the data is saved for that instance(reminder) on user selection of cell(in my case:sections with single row).

I can make the user navigate to the add reminder page,but how can I access the values corresponding to that reminder contained in table view sections.

For the user to make changes to the reminder,say phone number,date,message body etc... or what ever it is.

I made several attempts,searched various links googling but couldn't find a suitable and effective solution.

Here is how I retrieved reminders based on user saves in add reminder page :

```
-(void)loadgReminders
{
    self.frndsArray = nil;
    self.frndsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //Retrieve the group of reminder
    const char *thePath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;

    if (sqlite3_open(thePath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    NSString *getQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE Grp = 'Family'"];
        const char *sqlite_stmt = [getQuery UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB, sqlite_stmt, -1, &statment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                ReminderClass *remind = [[ReminderClass alloc]init];
                remind.Name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 1)];
                remind.Event = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 2)];
                remind.Date = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 3)];

                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remind.Date];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
                NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
                remind.Date = dateVal;

                [self.frndsArray addObject:remind];

                [remind release];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statment);
        }

        sqlite3_close(remindersDB);
    }
}
```

Please help me out with valuable suggestions

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tableview delegate method:

```
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

you access a member of your frndsArray.
Similarly, when the user selects a row,

```
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

is called on your delegate.

Just access the same member of the frndsArray (usually by indexPath.row), and pass this object to your detail/editing viewController, either in it's init method or by setting an iVar.

If you want to implement the SAVE operation in your detail view controller, you'll also need to pass the primary key to the detail VC, so it can do the sql update based on that key.

EDIT:
pseudo code:

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     ReminderClass *rem = (ReminderClass *)[self.frndsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     // Instantiate your detail/editor view controller,
     // and pass in the ReminderClass object to be edited.
     ReminderDetailViewController *rdvc = [[ReminderDetailViewController alloc] initWithReminder: rem];
     [self.navigationController pushNavigationController:rdvc animated:YES];
     [rdvc release];
 }
```

EDIT 2: more psuedo code (you'll need to do the #import and @synthesize and dealloc also)

In ReminderDetailViewController.h add this:

```
 @property(nonatomic, retain) ReminderClass *myLocalReminderInstance;
```

In ReminderDetailViewController.m, add this initializer method:

```
 -(id) initWithReminder:(ReminderClass *)aReminder {
       if ( (self=[super init]) ) {
            self.myLocalReminderInstance = aReminder;
       }
       return self;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but the description is bit confusing,can you please make it more clear,thanks once again :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edited answer.I understood all the intention from the code snippet.But I am not aware of how to pass the reminder class object to rdvc.More over I don't have any method called initWithReminder,need help in this aspect too!,thanks :)

Comment: You need to write that method for rdvc. See Edit 2.

Comment: Thanks a ton Rayfleck for all the concern and the answer,will implement and get back to you :)

Comment: Yeah discovered what's wrong,we need to pass the values to reminder class objects,i.e. textField.text = reminderInstance.Name,textField.text = reminderInstance.Event etc...

Thanks for the idea once again,that worked like a magic,don't mind the mistake from my side :P Cheers :)

Comment: One small help needed,how can I update the data saved after editing,When I click save,it is getting saved as another reminder,can you suggest me a tutorial or sample code,thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is getting beyond the scope of the original question, but I think you need to pass just a reference to your reminder object to the editor/saver class, and if you pass the correct object, it should save the correct object. Please open another question if you need help.

Comment: I am sorry for that but I am pretty much impressed with the way you answered,hence I wanted to clarify one more doubt from you ;) Anyway I will try or else will post a new question.Thanks for leading me in a right manner :)

Comment: Hi Rayfleck I strongly believe that you can solve my issue,please take a look at my question when you are free,thanks and regards in advance :)

Comment: Hi,sorry for troubling you again and again,I have been disabled for asking questions in stackoverflow,I have opened a new account,I have been facing with the crash issue,deletion,updation,insertion...everything's fine with sqlite3.But please have a look at this question when you find some free time:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091647/incorrect-number-of-objects-getting-added-to-mutable-array.Thanks in advance :)